# Nokogiri check if value exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm scraping some web stuff and I get the following error,

**scrape.rb:27:in `block in <main>': undefined method`text' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)**

when running my ruby task, due to the css not containing any content inside.

Is there a way to check if CSS is not undefined so it wont stop crawling? My code wont work :(

```
products.each do |product|

     web = Nokogiri::HTML(open(product))

      counter = products.index(product)

      if web.at_css('.entry-title').text != undefined
      puts "CSS content is not undefined"
      else
      puts "Error"
      end
```

Comment: What is `undefined` (or are you thinking of `nil`)?

Comment: It looks like you aren't using Nokogiri and the CSS selector correctly, but you're not telling us enough to know for sure. What is your input HTML? What is your expected output?

Answer (score 3):

You can just **IF** the object result before calling text

```
result = web.at_css('.entry-title')
if result
  puts "CSS content is not undefined"
  puts result.text
else
  puts "Error"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree at_css & IF is the best solution for testing a class existence. Here's an example I whipped up..

```
user_agents = ["Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0",
            "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Konqueror/3; Linux)",             
            "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.4) Gecko/20030624",
            "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.11; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0",
            "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; PPC Mac OS X Mach-O; en-US; rv:1.4a) Gecko/20030401",
            "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_2; de-at) AppleWebKit/531.21.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.4 Safari/531.21.10",
            "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2) AppleWebKit/601.3.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0.2 Safari/601.3.9",
            "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.125 Safari/537.36",
            "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)",
            "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)",
            "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)",
            "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)",
            "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0)",
            "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko", 
            "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2486.0 Safari/537.36 Edge/13.10586",
            "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.4b) Gecko/20030516 Mozilla Firebird/0.6",
            "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0",
            "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 9_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Mobile/13B5110e Safari/601.1",
            "Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 9_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Mobile/13B143 Safari/601.1",
            "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.1.1; Nexus 7 Build/LMY47V) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.76 Safari/537.36"]
user_agent = user_agents.sample

good_2_go = "https://gomovies.to/genre/action/1"
my_bad = "https://gomovies.to/genre/action/100"

crawls = []
crawls.push(good_2_go, my_bad)

crawls.each do |crawl|
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(crawl, 'User-Agent' => user_agent).read, nil, 'utf-8')

  entries = doc.at_css('.ml-item')

  if entries
      puts crawl
      puts "Found entries class, proceeding with scrape.."
  else
      puts crawl
      puts "Could not find base class for entries"
  end
end
```

This will STDOUT ...

```
=> https://gomovies.to/genre/action/1
   Found entries class, proceeding with scrape..
   https://gomovies.to/genre/action/100
   Could not find base class for entries
```